# Cross-platform direct file transfer across the internet

Tags: p2p

I want to directly transfer a file from a friend's PC running Windows to my Ubuntu box over the internet.

What are my options? For security reasons, I don't want to use a third-party server.

Hopefully, it's something not something complicated or command line based that requires a learning curve since I am the one requesting the friend to send the file to me.

Comment: Locally or remotely?

Comment: Remotely over the Internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Install [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) on the windows PC (it uses `sftp` which is part of `ssh`) and set up [`ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/ssh) on your system allowing him access to a `directory` or `share`. Install
  [openssh-server](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openssh-server)[image: Install openssh-server] if not already there.

  And this [how to](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/openssh-server.html) should still work on setting it up: basically you need to open a port, create a user (and password) and tell your windows user to insert your IP adress, the port, username and password into winscp.
- Ubuntu One is made for this too.
- Do not forget about the ability of mailing it or using a free file sharing website like [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/). These 2 are very low tech and require no installation (unless he or you has no mail ;) ).
- ... and just for fun... if the 2 of you use torrents he could make it a torrent and give you the announcement (you can create trackers at [openbittorrent](http://www.openbittorrent.com/)).

Comment: I'm just weird, so I don't want to use any method like email or file-sharing which isn't direct and involves the file going to a third-party server beyond our control.

Comment: SSH, how do I set it up?

Comment: That's why the invented encryption ;) The 1st one is a straight 1 to 1 copy. If you want I know a few more but the 1st is should be the easiest. I put in an install option for ssh. You still need to set it up though (trying to find a short config method ;) )

Comment: OpenSSH is installed on Ubuntu by default. I need to know how to set up SSH server so my computer can be connected to and the file transferred.

Comment: Eh I sure hope `openssh client` is installed by default and not `openssh server`; I put in a how to from Ubuntu help.

Comment: Well, I don't know if the server part is in a different package, but I sure can `ssh` into stuff without installing anything.

Comment: I am asking of you a bit too much, but can you please detail what and how I need to set up in SSH server to receive the file, and needs to be done with WinSCP to send the file?

Comment: I would love too but have been told to answer the question and not to elaborate. I'd suggest creating a new q so I can answer that one >-)

Comment: Well, we're not going off-topic - you told me what to do, and I asking how we can do that. Or should I make two separate questions, one asking how to set up SSH server and shares that you suggest, and the other asking how to use WinSCP to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing [CopSSH](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) on your friend's machine. It is a SFTP server implementation for Windows (with a GUI) that enforces per-user authorisation and uses a normally port-forwarded port 22 as S stands for SSH. All you need to do is add yourself to the activated users list. Then you can just connect to your friend using nautilus.

Comment: Does this not install a server on the windows PC? That sounds like the wrong way around.

Comment: It installs the server on the Windows PC.