# How to transfer files from remote ubuntu server to remote ubuntu server?

Tags: migration, p2p

I have tried TeamViewer, AnyDesk, NitroShare and by torrents to transfer my files to a new server. 
TeamViewer did not connect, NitroShare is for local computers and by torrents does not work because no seeds. I have tried with trackers but also did not work.
Since I am desperate because I have 2 hours to migrate the files, I came for help here, if you have any method to transfer

I have also searched for similar questions but all are about local computers
I use Ubuntu 16.04

And is a 70GiB folder

Comment: Check [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61831/cross-platform-direct-file-transfer-across-the-internet?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have ssh access to both machines, try [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

`scp` will probably only work when one of the two machines is local. You could ssh into Server1 and

`scp -r /your/source/* username@server2:/your/destination/`

(or vice versa).

Comment: Works but I forget to say that was a folder…

Comment: Well, to transfer needed the * after the directory
`scp /your/source/*`

Comment: And I should add for the future readers that to transfer the files is useful to use `scp -r /directory/* username@server2:/destination/`
because _-r_ causes all files to be transferred

Comment: Sure, I was focusing more on the servers you are doing this on, than on the files you want to transfer. I'll edit my answer, thank you. I still prefer rsync though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
scp -r username@server1:/path_to_source_directory/* username@server2:/ path_to_the_destination_directory/
```

Comment: I have tried `scp -r root@158.69.23.180:/home/_/ root@149.56.243.239:/home/`
but nothing, when I enter the pass say: Host key verification failed.
lost connection

Comment: @Ignacio-Pozo seems like something changed with your keys, try deleting them with eg "rm /home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts" from the servers and your machine

Comment: @maRei not necessarily. Sometimes Linux asks every time whether it should trust a new host.